# Carousel view SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, carousel

How to achieve the Rotary type Carousel present in the [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) Framework of swift. The following is what I wanted to achieve with the SwiftUI

[image]

I checked many tutorials and the framework present but I could not able to achieve as shown above image

Comment: Does this help? https://www.appcoda.com/learnswiftui/swiftui-carousel.html

Comment: @MrDeveloper Thanks for the reply. I checked that too but not matching my requirement.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here is a general approach: All items are drawn above each other in a `ZStack`, then their position and opacity is changed based on the "distance" to the foremost element.

The demo has a fixed size for the item, but can easily be adapted. Change the values in `opacity` and `scaleEffect`to your wishes.

[image]

```
struct Item: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var title: String
    var color: Color
}

class Store: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [Item]
    
    let colors: [Color] = [.red, .orange, .blue, .teal, .mint, .green, .gray, .indigo, .black]

    // dummy data
    init() {
        items = []
        for i in 0...7 {
            let new = Item(id: i, title: "Item \(i)", color: colors[i])
            items.append(new)
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var store = Store()
    @State private var snappedItem = 0.0
    @State private var draggingItem = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            ForEach(store.items) { item in
                
                // article view
                ZStack {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 18)
                        .fill(item.color)
                    Text(item.title)
                        .padding()
                }
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                
                .scaleEffect(1.0 - abs(distance(item.id)) * 0.2 )
                .opacity(1.0 - abs(distance(item.id)) * 0.3 )
                .offset(x: myXOffset(item.id), y: 0)
                .zIndex(1.0 - abs(distance(item.id)) * 0.1)
            }
        }
        .gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged { value in
                    draggingItem = snappedItem + value.translation.width / 100
                }
                .onEnded { value in
                    withAnimation {
                        draggingItem = snappedItem + value.predictedEndTranslation.width / 100
                        draggingItem = round(draggingItem).remainder(dividingBy: Double(store.items.count))
                        snappedItem = draggingItem
                    }
                }
        )
    }
    
    func distance(_ item: Int) -> Double {
        return (draggingItem - Double(item)).remainder(dividingBy: Double(store.items.count))
    }
    
    func myXOffset(_ item: Int) -> Double {
        let angle = Double.pi * 2 / Double(store.items.count) * distance(item)
        return sin(angle) * 200
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Excellent Approach, Thanks, is it possible to show from Index 0 to items.count and smoothen the scroll for smaller item size and end the scroll when it reaches on both side (Index 0 or items.count)

Comment: is it possible to detect current index in this code ?

Comment: @SadmanSamee on my case i change 

**draggingItem = snappedItem + value.predictedEndTranslation.width / 100**

to this 

**draggingItem = snappedItem + val.translation.width / 100**

Comment: @ChrisR Is there is a way to change it on Button Click also?

Comment: Very nice. The other thing you did @ChrisR was helped me better understand why I would use StateObject.  From playing with this I see I want to use StateObject where the View itself controls itself controls the objects lifecycle. In my case, other views need that information so I may use Observable Obj...but it is very helpful

Comment: @ChrisR is there any way to set the active item on load?

Comment: Hey @ChrisR, In the beginning, thanks for this approach

Now I have a Question: What if I want to do it in the Linear way inside the routing?

like here 

https://camo.githubusercontent.com/74615f988a4a2be5f43db6d04e69b23c0f79d7ec28a7cf0095a79681160d365e/687474703a2f2f672e7265636f726469742e636f2f78743836694b334137662e676966

Comment: @umair151 to set the active item on load just assign a start value to `draggingItem` AND `snappedItem`.

Comment: @AbdelrahmanMohamed just get rid of the `.scaleEffect` and adapt the radius in `myXOffset` e.g. from 200 to 300. Of course this "carousel" still keeps items in a circle. It looks like you want it fully linear ...

Comment: Hey, @ChrisR, thanks again. 

I have another question.

Can we add space between the current, previous, and subsequent images?

Since my view has the whole picture with 20 px padding from the right and left?

https://github.com/obadasemary/HomeScreenSwiftUIExample/blob/main/Simulator%20Screenshot%20-%20i14Pro%20-%202023-09-10%20at%2009.44.45.png

Answer (score 8):

Thank you [@ChrisR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17896776/chrisr) this is a great way to achieve Carousel experience.

Added active index in the [@ChrisR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17896776/chrisr)'s answer, that might be useful for someone.

[@ChrisR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17896776/chrisr) once you add active index in your answer, I can remove my post.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Item: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var title: String
    var color: Color
}

class Store: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [Item]
    
    let colors: [Color] = [.red, .orange, .blue, .teal, .mint, .green, .gray, .indigo, .black]
    
    // dummy data
    init() {
        items = []
        for i in 0...7 {
            let new = Item(id: i, title: "Item \(i)", color: colors[i])
            items.append(new)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var store = Store()
    @State private var snappedItem = 0.0
    @State private var draggingItem = 0.0
    @State var activeIndex: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            ForEach(store.items) { item in
                
                // article view
                ZStack {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 18)
                        .fill(item.color)
                    Text(item.title)
                        .padding()
                }
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                
                .scaleEffect(1.0 - abs(distance(item.id)) * 0.2 )
                .opacity(1.0 - abs(distance(item.id)) * 0.3 )
                .offset(x: myXOffset(item.id), y: 0)
                .zIndex(1.0 - abs(distance(item.id)) * 0.1)
            }
        }
        .gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged { value in
                    draggingItem = snappedItem + value.translation.width / 100
                }
                .onEnded { value in
                    withAnimation {
                        draggingItem = snappedItem + value.predictedEndTranslation.width / 100
                        draggingItem = round(draggingItem).remainder(dividingBy: Double(store.items.count))
                        snappedItem = draggingItem
                        
                        //Get the active Item index
                        self.activeIndex = store.items.count + Int(draggingItem)
                        if self.activeIndex > store.items.count || Int(draggingItem) >= 0 {
                            self.activeIndex = Int(draggingItem)
                        }
                        print(self.activeIndex)
                    }
                }
        )
    }
    
    func distance(_ item: Int) -> Double {
        return (draggingItem - Double(item)).remainder(dividingBy: Double(store.items.count))
    }
    
    func myXOffset(_ item: Int) -> Double {
        let angle = Double.pi * 2 / Double(store.items.count) * distance(item)
        return sin(angle) * 200
    }
}
```

Comment: can we set activeIndex on load to show different item on first load?

Comment: Hey @Anupam Mishra, In the beginning, thanks for additional info

Now I have a Question: What if I want to do it in the Linear way inside the routing?

like here 

https://camo.githubusercontent.com/74615f988a4a2be5f43db6d04e69b23c0f79d7ec28a7cf0095a79681160d365e/687474703a2f2f672e7265636f726469742e636f2f78743836694b334137662e676966