# SwiftUI ScrollView - iOS 17

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, scrollview, ios17

Following is the animation i want to achieve, when the view appears until the scrollview is scrolled the views are stacked one behind the other, and when they are scrolled it appears side by side.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    private let colors: [Color] = [.red, .green, .blue, .yellow, .purple, .black, .brown, .cyan, .gray, .indigo, .orange, .pink, .mint, .teal]
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                LazyHStack(spacing: 10.0) {
                    ForEach(colors, id: \.self) { color in
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0)
                            .foregroundStyle(color)
                            .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
                            .scrollTransition { content, phase in
                                content
                                    .opacity(phase.isIdentity ? 1: 0.2)
                                    .scaleEffect(y: phase.isIdentity ? 1.0 : 0.8)
                            }
                    }
                }
                .scrollTargetLayout()
            }
            .contentMargins(60.0, for: .scrollContent)
            .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
            .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
            .frame(maxHeight: 400.0)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Expected output: 
 [image]

I am able to get the views side by side, but how to get the views arranged one behind and then smoothly transition to side by side when scrolled.

Here is my code output:
 [image]

Thanks to Mat, have got until here, need help to bring both the two looks together:

```
struct ColorViewModel: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let color: Color
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    private let colors: [ColorViewModel] = [.init(id: 0, color: .red), .init(id: 1, color: .yellow), .init(id: 2, color: .green), .init(id: 03, color: .blue), .init(id: 04, color: .purple), .init(id: 05, color: .pink), .init(id: 06, color: .brown), .init(id: 07, color: .indigo), .init(id: 08, color: .black), .init(id: 09, color: .teal), .init(id: 10, color: .gray), .init(id: 011, color: .white), .init(id: 012, color: .cyan)]

    @State private var hasScrolled: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack(spacing: 10.0) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< colors.count, id: \.self) { number in
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/25.0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                            .frame(maxHeight: 300.0)
                            .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
                            .foregroundStyle(colors[number].color)
                            .if(!hasScrolled) { view in
                                view
                                    .padding(.trailing, colors[number].id == colors.last?.id ? 0 : -220)
                                    .zIndex(CGFloat(-number))
                            }
//                            .scrollTransition { content, phase in
//                                content
//                                    .opacity(phase.isIdentity ? 1 : 0.2)
//                                    .scaleEffect(y: phase.isIdentity ? 1.0 : 0.8)
//                            }
                    }
                }
                .scrollTargetLayout()
            }
            .contentMargins(60.0, for: .scrollContent)
            .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    @ViewBuilder func `if`<Content: View>(_ condition: Bool, transform: (Self) -> Content) -> some View {
        if condition {
            transform(self)
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like a re-invention of [this carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72352181/20386264)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve that you can play with rotation values and spacings between items. You can do that by doing something like this:

```
struct CoverFlowView<Content: View, Item: RandomAccessCollection>: View where Item.Element: Identifiable {
    
    //MARK: - PROPERTIES
    
    /// Customization
    var itemWidth: CGFloat
    var spacing: CGFloat = .zero
    var rotation: CGFloat = .zero
    
    var items: Item
    var content: (Item.Element) -> Content
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader {
            let size = $0.size
            
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                LazyHStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(items) { item in
                        content(item)
                            .frame(width: itemWidth)
                            .visualEffect { content, geometryProxy in
                                content
                                    .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(rotation(geometryProxy)),
                                                      axis: (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0),
                                                      anchor: .center)
                            }
                            .padding(.trailing, item.id == items.last?.id ? 0 : spacing)
                    } //: LOOP ITEMS
                } //: LAZY HSTACK
                .padding(.horizontal, (size.width - itemWidth) / 2)
                .scrollTargetLayout()
            } //: SCROLL
            .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
            .scrollClipDisabled()
            
        } //: GEOMETRY
        
    }
    
    
    //MARK: - Functions
    func rotation(_ proxy: GeometryProxy) -> Double {
        let scrollViewWidth = proxy.bounds(of: .scrollView(axis: .horizontal))?.width ?? 0
        let midX = proxy.frame(in: .scrollView(axis: .horizontal)).midX
        /// Converting into progress
        let progress = midX / scrollViewWidth
        /// Capping progress 0-1
        let cappedProgress = max(min(progress, 1), 0)
        
        /// Limit rotation between 0-90°
        let cappedRotation = max(min(rotation, 90), 0)
        
        let degree = cappedProgress * (cappedRotation * 2)
        
        return cappedRotation - degree
    }
    
}
```

And you use it like this:

```
/// State variables
@State private var spacing: CGFloat = 0
@State private var rotation: CGFloat = 0
@State private var mirrorCards = false

CoverFlowView(itemWidth: 250,
                          spacing: spacing,
                          rotation: rotation,
                          items: items) { item in
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                    .fill(item.color.gradient)
            }
            .frame(height: 180)
            .rotation3DEffect(
                .degrees(mirrorCards ? 180 : 0),
                axis: (x: 0.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0)
            )
            ///Gesture
            .gesture(
                DragGesture()
                    .onChanged({ value in
                        let predictedTranslationX = value.predictedEndTranslation.width
                        print("Predicted end: \(predictedTranslationX)")
                        if predictedTranslationX >= 60 {
                            /// Close Cards
                            withAnimation {
                                spacing = -250
                            }
                        } else if predictedTranslationX <= 150 {
                            withAnimation {
                                spacing = -100
                            }
                        }
                    })
            )
            /// Or if you want it to work with tap gesture
            .onTapGesture {
                if spacing == -250 {
                    withAnimation {
                        spacing = -100
                    }
                } else if spacing == -100 {
                    withAnimation {
                        spacing = -220
                    }
                }
            }
```

The item I'm using in this simple case is just an Identifiable struct with a color property, but you can use anything you like really.
If you use a spacing of around -220 and the mirror effect (by using the rotation3DEffect) you can achieve a similar result to the one you are looking for:

[image: Overlapping Cards]

Let me know how did you find this solution!

Comment: Thank you @MatBuompy, your code got me started, do we need to do the mirrorEffect, i was able to get until here, but now im not able to get both these pieces to work together, adding the code to the question

Comment: The mirror effect was just a new thing I added to my existing code to make it look like you wanted, since your movies were oriented the other side basically. I don't get where it is that you are stuck now. Can you show a gif of your actual result? Did you set the spacing to around -220 as I said in the answer? With that you should have the overlapping effect already.

Comment: The piece im stuck on is smoothly animating the two things together ie, have the views overlap and when the user scrolls seperate them out. I have added my version of the code to the original question. Added the gif to the question

Comment: Ok, now I see it. You may need a drag gesture for it maybe. I can look into it tomorrow. By the way I would appreciate it if you could at least upvote my answer since it helped you quite a bit.

Comment: Yeah sorry, absolutely, will mark your answer as the correct one as well once we reach a solution. I tried the Geometry reader to get the scroll offset and also the scroll position, it didnt quite work as expected.

Comment: @bubu I've updated the code with the Drag Gesture and also an example if you wanted with the onTap. I don't know the exact specifics of your animation since I can't see the finger in the gif with the movie carousel, so I don't know if it should work with gestures or tap. To make it work you need to save the spacing as a State variable of course, because I'm changing cards positions using spacing. Let me know.

Comment: thank you Mat, will mark your answer correct, i just will have to make a few tweeks but your solution helped a lot, thanks again mate!