# SwiftUI ScrollView peeking next and previous item

Tags: swiftui, scrollview

I'm going to create a `ScrollView` that contains 10 `RoundedRectangle()` in it, I want it to only show  one rectangle on screen but it also can peeking next and previous item a little, to remind user there's other rectangle they can scroll.
I added with a `.scrollTargetLayout()`and also `.scrollTargetLayoutBehavior(.viewAligned)`, also, each item in `ScrollView` was added a `.containerRelativeFrame(_:)` to make sure there's only one rectangle will appear on the screen, and the last one is `.scrollPosition(id: )` to control what rectangle should appear.
but it seems that there's one rectangle on the screen, **so how should I change my code to let the next and previous item can be peeked?**
these are my code below:

```swift
struct CardTheme: View {
    @State private var scrollID: Int? = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack {
                ForEach(0..<10, id: \.self) { i in
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                        .frame(width: 280, height: 450)
                        .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal, count: 1, spacing: 16)
                }
            }
            .scrollTargetLayout()
        }
        .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
        .scrollPosition(id: $scrollID)
    }
}
```

[The result I want to see is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ic2g9.jpg)
[This is mine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvgKv.png)

I have tried change the number of count in this code: `.containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal, count: 1, spacing: 16)` and deleted `frame()`, while the number was more than 3, I could see the next item on the screen
[the preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3Vhp.png)
[changed code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pNgl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `containerRelativeFrame` you will always end up occupying the entire view as far as I know. So, what I've done is that I used a `GeometryReader` to get the size of the `ScrollView` subtracted the width of your `RoundedRectangle` dividing it all by 2 and applied its value as an horizontal padding to the `HStack` wrapped around your Rectangle:

```
struct CardTheme: View {
    @State private var scrollID: Int? = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            let size = proxy.size
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(0..<10, id: \.self) { i in
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                            .frame(width: 280, height: 450)
                            /// Remove this line
                            //.containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal, count: 1, spacing: 16)
                    }
                }
                /// 280 is the width of your item. Change it as needed.
                .padding(.horizontal, (size.width - 280) / 2)
                .scrollTargetLayout()
            }
            .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
            .scrollPosition(id: $scrollID)
        }
    }
}
```

If you want better customisation or control over this, you can check out [this project](https://github.com/MatHeartGaming/coolStuff_with_SwiftUI/tree/main/CoverFlow%20With%20Reflections) and getting the `CoverFlowView` file from it, which creates a customisable paged `ScrollView` just like yours but that is much more flexible since you can give it any spacing you want between items etc, which I made thanks to YouTuber [Kavsoft](https://www.youtube.com/@Kavsoft), so credtis to him, which I also used in a modified version with some gestures in an answere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77869660/swiftui-scrollview-ios-17/77872074#77872074).

Here's the result with just the code I posted above:

[image: Peeking ScrollView]

Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: sorry but can u explain why `(size.width - itemWidth) / 2` will center the middle item?

Comment: Basically it adds the same amount of padding left and right to the Hstack which includes all the rectangles. This padding pushes items towards themselves making them peek. I can do more testing on this to give you more examples if you want.