Is it possible to loop a SwiftUI ScrollView to repeat infinitely?
I have a horizontal scroll view and a fixed array. I would like to loop it such that when I scroll left and get near the end, the array will add the items in the beginning to the end so that the user can continue to scroll. I would like this to happen when scrolling both left and right and to not have the current position of the user jump around. Here is my code. What am I missing? Would appreciate any and all help.
import SwiftUI
import Algorithms

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var timePosition = ScrollPosition(idType: Int.self, edge: .leading)
    @State private var times: [Int] = Array(0...23)
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            LazyHStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(times, id:\.self) { time in
                    Text("\(time)")
                        .font(.system(.callout, design: .monospaced, weight: .semibold))
                        .padding(8)
                        .frame(width: 180, height: 110, alignment: .topLeading)
                        .border(width: 1, edges: [.leading, .trailing], color: .primary.opacity(0.05))
                        .id(time)
                }
            }
            .scrollTargetLayout()
        }
        .frame(height: 110)
        .scrollPosition($timeScrollPosition, anchor: .center)
        .onScrollTargetVisibilityChange(idType: Int.self) { timeIDs in
            if let currentViewID = model.timeScrollPosition.viewID {
                if timeIDs.contains(times[times.count - 2]) {
                    times.rotate(toStartAt: times.count - 1)
                }
                
                if timeIDs.contains(times[1]) {
                    times.rotate(toStartAt: times.count-1)
                }
                
                print("New times: \(times)")
                timeScrollPosition.scrollTo(id: currentViewID)
            }
        }
    }
}


Unrelated but ForEach(times, id:\.self) needs to be changed to ForEach(0..<24) to prevent a crash because of invalid id key path.

There are a number of similar post/answers on SO and examples on the net, search using the word carousel.
For example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72343827/carousel-view-swiftui
and
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76824297/swiftui-infinite-carousel-with-tabview-and-asyncimage-how-to-achieve-carousel/76824473#76824473

@workingdogsupportUkraine none of those achieve what i want
